# Pinging an IP address from iOS code

Tags: iphone, ipad, networking

How do you ping an IP address from your iOS app code? Is it same as trying to connect to it via NSURLConnection?

Comment: Maybe similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798454/how-to-write-a-simple-ping-method-in-cocoa-objective-c

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to apple's sample code:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html

It is the same code iOS and OS X