# Reachability iOS doesn't work fine

Tags: ios, reachability

We are developing a module, which checks whether the Internet connection either is active or not active or disabled. The previous scenarios work well, except the case if there is a WI-FI connection but the internet is not active. We have made sure that the data mobile connection (3G, 4G) is not enabled.

We have seen that everybody recommends using the Tony Million's Reachability class, which replaces the Apple's one.

Below, there is the code that we are using:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"]; //Cambiar por el servidor

    reachability.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
        NSLog(@"Network is reachable.");

    };

    reachability.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
       NSLog(@"Network is unreachable.");

    };

    // Start Monitoring
    [reachability startNotifier];

    return YES;
}
```

Whether there is a WI-FI connection but the internet is not active, it does not work because it goes to:

```
reachability.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
    NSLog(@"Network is reachable.");
}
```

instead of

```
reachability.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
   NSLog(@"Network is unreachable.");

}
```

What we are missing?

Thank you in advance,

Regards

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411606/reachability-not-working-when-wi-fi-connected-but-no-internet?rq=1

Comment: I've used this, and it's great: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability It's what's I put into the Pandemic iPad app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
- (BOOL)isNetAvailable
{
    BOOL isNetAvailable = NO;

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus != NotReachable)
    {
        isNetAvailable = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        isNetAvailable = NO;
    }
    return  isNetAvailable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
NSURLRequest *nsrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:nsrequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if(response.statusCode==0){
    NSLog(@"Network is unreachable.");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Network is reachable.");
}
```