# Why i get timeout erros when page is not available

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, http

I use `NSString` method `initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` to get content of some page. I notice, when page that i try to access is not exist this method is executed long time and then fail with timeout error. I tried to use `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` classes for the same purposes, but get the same result - execution long time and then timeout error.
When i try to open the same page in browser, i get response more quickly and it returns page is not available error.

It looks like cocoa methods don't do a dns resolution for page name, or they have  longer timeout for that operation.

So my question, does cocoa method that i use do dns resolve? How to do that if they didn't?

Samples of code i use:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://unexisting.domain.local"]; 
NSError* err = nil;
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil error:&err];

if (err) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", err); 
} else {
    NSLog(@"content: %@", content);
}
```

---

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://unexisting.domain.local"]; 
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* err = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

if (err) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", err); 
} else {
    NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"content: %@", content);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why use ".local" as Top Level Domain ? For testing purposes or is this only in a local network?

Comment: If I use your code with url unexisting.domain.ch it's very fast.

Comment: I use local just for testing purposes. Actually, i have to access host  in local network also. You're right when use of "unexisting.com" - it's fast, instead when user just "unexisting" - it hangs up for a while. It could be some problems with dns in my local network...

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798454/how-to-write-a-simple-ping-method-in-cocoa-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gene M. [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085082/111015) how to do that with using of `SCNetworkReachability`. Here is sample code:

```
bool success = false;
const char *host_name = [@"stackoverflow.com" 
                         cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL,
                                                                        host_name);
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
bool isAvailable = success && (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) && 
                             !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
if (isAvailable) {
    NSLog(@"Host is reachable: %d", flags);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Host is unreachable");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely good practice to monitor the reachability (device connectivity) and react to it as noted above.

You can also implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol and its methods such as

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
      NSLog(@"**ERROR** %@", error);
      // Respond to error
 }
```

If you're not connected you should get an NSURLConnection error code of 999 and `NSURLErrorCancelled = -999` and/or a `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009` if you're not connected, etc. At least you'd have a report back of what's going on.

Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html