# How to test the availability of URL or NOT?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not found simple solution for this question on SO. 
I need simple check logic for my URL and return `YES` - if available or `NO` - if not.

What i found:

```
-(BOOL)connectedToNetwork  {
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com/"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if (data != nil)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

founded [this](https://coderwall.com/p/6fxe3g/check-connection-availability-on-ios-the-simple-way)
But i need more correctly answer.

**UPD**

I found [SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Listings/SimplePing_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-SimplePing_m-DontLinkElementID_5) by Apple.

**UPD1**

Found answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085082/887325) Thx all!

**UPD2**

Better solution [SimplePingHelper](http://www.splinter.com.au/how-to-ping-a-server-in-objective-c-iphone/) required [SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html):

```
- (void)tapPing {
    [SimplePingHelper ping:@"www.google.com"
        target:self sel:@selector(pingResult:)];
}

- (void)pingResult:(NSNumber*)success {
    if (success.boolValue) {
        [self log:@"SUCCESS"];
    } else {
        [self log:@"FAILURE"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Best comment "
If you just need to know if you can get data or not, HTTP supports headers called no-content and special HTTP methods just for this... by using this method you not only block that thread but waste network bandwidth and battery. Bad. –  @Michael Voznesensky"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a simple Ping method in Cocoa/Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798454/how-to-write-a-simple-ping-method-in-cocoa-objective-c)

Comment: -(BOOL)connectedToNetwork  {
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com/"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if (data != nil)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
  This is correct answer. check it first.

Comment: @AshokLondhe yea it's correct but have a lack, notice how the guys, its downloaded url.

Comment: "If you tried to check if a link to a video is available this way, your users would kill you) –  FreeNickname", but as Simple solution is the best  :)

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76603/discussion-between-bimawa-and-ashok-londhe).

Answer (score 1):

The preferred approach is trying to connect, and if that fails due to the host is not reachable check and monitor the network state. See [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). If the network state indicates that a host can be possibly reached, try again.

There are also a couple of third party libs that implement a handy API over Apple's Reachability interface.

Comment: Yea Reachability is good, but very powerful, i need more simple solution.

Comment: @Bimawa This is the most simple solution that works ;)

Comment: i finger up for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to check reachability.

Pod file: `pod "AFNetworking"`

You have to include `AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h` in the file you want to use it.

This is a sample, basic code to check reachability.

```
// -- Start monitoring network reachability (globally available) -- //
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];

    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {

        NSLog(@"Reachability changed: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));


        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                // -- Reachable -- //
                NSLog(@"Reachable");
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            default:
                // -- Not reachable -- //
                NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
                break;
        }

    }];
```

Comment: there is also a gun on sparrows

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: sry me, i just try say its not simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

A valid URL is made of these characters :

```
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=
```

You simply need to make a String checking function to validate your URL's characters are falling in or out.

Comment: Guys, i need check available URL not validate. Just ping

Answer (score -1):

Its was simple:

```
-(BOOL)connectedToNetwork  {
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com/"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if (data != nil)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

founded [this](https://coderwall.com/p/6fxe3g/check-connection-availability-on-ios-the-simple-way)

Comment: This is wrong, your answer tells him wether or not he is connected to Google, not the validity of his URL.

Comment: be careful I do not need validation URL, i need know:"Can i get data or not?"

Comment: If you tried to check if a link to a video is available this way, your users would kill you)

Comment: @Bhavin ok. one moment

Comment: If you just need to know if you can get data or not, HTTP supports headers called no-content and special HTTP methods just for this... by using this method you not only block that thread but waste network bandwidth and battery. Bad.

Comment: its stay very simple solution

Comment: @Bhavin, this is perfectly acceptable, and it is specifically mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). The answer is not very good in this case, though :)

Comment: @Bhavin, well, the OP, I guess, believed that this is actually a solution)

Comment: @FreeNickname according to me..if he actually wants to check that host is available or not at this time...he should use reachability

Comment: @Bhavin, I'm completely agree with you. I just wanted to say, that the OP actually thought that this is a nice working solution, that's why he/she posted it as an answer.